# Kohana 3.2: Роутинг на существующий URL

Tags: роутинг, kohana

Как сделать роут на существующий URL, минуя стандартный роут на контроллер ?

Ситуация такая: Есть url, т.е. на моем сайте есть папка с демками, которая не пренадлежит Kohana, но лежит в корне сайта, иногда мне нужно выводить какую-нть демо-страницу от туда минуя все и вся, стандартно роут делается так:

```
// РОУТЫ НА ДЕМКИ
Route::set('demoform','demo/php/form/index.html')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'mycontroller',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Вот тут загвоздка, по сути хотелось бы вместо `defaults` подставить чистый url, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вроде вообще роуты не нужны - если файлы физически существуют, все запросы будут идти к ним напрямую минуя Кохану

Comment: дело в том что как ни крути, кохана отправит меня в какой-то роут, а никак не на физически существующий файл.

Comment: У меня появилась мысль вообще в .htaccess прописать эту ссылку и не мучиться (хотя в этом тоже нужен help). Просто у меня роутов 50.

Comment: хотя, все правильно вы сказали, это я не понял почему у меня ссылка не срабатывает, а срабатывает роут, просто ссылка была неверна. Спасибо за помощь!